# Check if call is coming from a fixed or mobile phone with tasker

Tags: calls, tasker

I'm setting up a profile in tasker that sends a text message to everyone who calls me during a meeting. However, I don't want to waste my my credit by sending messages to fixed phones. How can I check if the call came from a mobile phone before sending the message?

Where I live, all mobile numbers start with 9 or 8, so I thought I might be able to use that. But I haven't be able to find a way to check what is the first digit in a number with tasker. Is there another way to do this? My objective is for tasker to know if the call came from a mobile or fixed phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the set up of your profile use the following:

In the Task step add the If statement: `%CNUM` ~ `9*/8*`
This means that the step will be executed only for number starting with 9 or 8.

Alternatively, set up the whole profile to only activate if the caller's number starts with 8 or 9.
In Event (like Incoming Call) settings: Caller (normally says *Optional*) specify `9*/8*`
This means the profile will be only activated if the number starts with 9 or 8.

Hopefully, this will work for you.

For more info see: http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/matching.html